# Method scope only inside another method

Tags: java, design-patterns, refactoring

I have a [Long Method](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/long-method) with lots of [Duplicated Code](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/duplicated-code). In order to fix this [Code Smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell), I'd like to use [Extract Method](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/extract-method). However, the extracted methods are only useful within the scope of the aforementioned Long Method, so making them accessible somewhere else inside my class looks to me like another —though lesser— Code Smell.

How would one approach this problem? Is it possible —maybe by using a clever [Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern)— to have a private method be accessible only within another private method of the same class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not pull your long method out into a separate method *object* and put your private extracted method, so it's available only to that method object ?

```
public class LongCalculator {
   public void longMethod() {
      innerMethod();
   }

   private void innerMethod() {
     // ...
   }
}
```

You could declare an object with your method-specific function *inside* your long method, but that's starting to look nasty (you'd likely require a specific interface or class definition)

Note as an aside that Scala (I mention Scala simply because I'm familiar with it and it's a JVM language) permits functions *within* functions specifically for this issue. Not a solution for you but worth noting that other languages have patterns/facilities for precisely your problem.

Comment: +1  This would be using [Replace Method with Method Object](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceMethodWithMethodObject.html)